# How to calculate LCBDs (local contributions to beta diversity), using only a subset of dyads in a dissimilarity matrix?

Tags: r

I'm using beta.div() function in adespatial package in r to try to calculate LCBD indices, comparing community data of gut microbiota across a population of their host mice. The default LCBD indicates uniqueness of each community compared to all other communities, but I would like my LCBD indices to reflect uniqueness of a community compared only to a set of other communities (neighbouring hosts) within the whole population of mouse hosts. Is there a way to limit the calculation of individual/site-wise LCBD to a subset of dyads in the dissimilarity matrix?